# Why would a SQL statement work when made to the DB, but not through a WCF?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

I'm still new to .NET, and I can't figure why a sql statement that worked fine from application to DB, now doesn't work when I'm trying to offload it to the service. I have a Winform that has a date, carrier and uploader checkbox, depending on what's checked, the sql statement should adhere to it like it does when the app talks to the DB. Do I have to write an OperationContract for EVERY SINGLE possible option? (i.e., date alone, date and carrier, date and uploader, etc....) Thanks!

```
public DataSet GetStatTableYear(StatDetails statInfo)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=vurdevice;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), CreateDate, 112) AS cPeriod, COUNT(DISTINCT IMEINo) AS TotalIMEINo, COUNT(*) AS TotalImageCnt, SUM(FileSize) AS TotalFileSize
                FROM VR_Image
                WHERE (@Uploader IS NULL OR Uploader = @Uploader) 
                AND (@CarrierID IS NULL OR CarrierID = @CarrierID) 
                AND DeleteDate IS NULL
                GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), CreateDate, 112)
                ORDER BY cPeriod", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarrierID", statInfo.CarrierID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uploader", statInfo.Uploader);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery()` doesn't return any values. `sda.Fill()` already fills your data set, there's no need to execute the command twice. Also, make sure to use `using` for everything that can be disposed (`con`, `cmd`, `ds`). None of this answers your question, incidentally.

Comment: Wrap your SqlConnection, SqlCommand, and SqlDataAdapter inside using() statements.  This is very important for the SqlConnection as you will leak Connections and a very busy Service will exhaust their connection pool.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert, No it doesn't, but still very valuable advice nonetheless. I will make sure to apply your advice for future coding, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked perfectly. Since the service kept ignoring the sql statement......

```
WHERE (Uploader IS NULL OR Uploader = @Uploader)
AND (CarrierID IS NULL OR CarrierID = @CarrierID)
```

I assigned DBNull to it when nothing was available, and it works fine now.

***NEW CODE***

```
public DataSet GetStatTableYear(StatDetails statInfo)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=vurdevice;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), CreateDate, 112) AS cPeriod, COUNT(DISTINCT IMEINo) AS TotalIMEINo, COUNT(*) AS TotalImageCnt, SUM(FileSize) AS TotalFileSize
                    FROM VR_Image
                    WHERE (Uploader IS NULL OR Uploader = @Uploader) 
                    AND (CarrierID IS NULL OR CarrierID = @CarrierID) 
                    AND DeleteDate IS NULL
                    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), CreateDate, 112)
                    ORDER BY cPeriod", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarrierID", statInfo.CarrierID == null ? DBNull.Value.ToString() : statInfo.CarrierID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uploader", statInfo.Uploader == null ? DBNull.Value.ToString() : statInfo.Uploader);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            return ds;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A simpler version of `statInfo.CarrierID == null ? DBNull.Value.ToString() : statInfo.CarrierID` is `statInfo.CarrierID ?? DBNull.Value.ToString()`.

Answer (score 3):

in your connection string you are using integrated security, it means that Windows Authentication is used to establish the connection.

Your Windows Forms application is running under your Windows Account security context and it can connect.

unless you enable it in IIS and web.config, the WCF application is most likely not using Windows Authentication and in this case I believe the IIS APP Pool identity / account has no access to the database to establish that connection.

this is my best guess at this stage given you have not explained details of the failure you receive.

Comment: Error states that the service is waiting for @@CarrierID and @@Uploader. But shouldn't the service process normally since the statement states that those variables can have a value OR be null?